# Can you program a character exception into a numeric column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with some strength and conditioning data and the trainer entered a "INJ" into a numeric column of the csv if the player was injured at the time of the testing. I am wondering if I can program an exception into the MySQL numeric column for that variable to allow "INJ" as a valid entry. I would normally just use a NULL value for this, but there are also some NULL values in these columns and I need to differentiate them.

I would like it to be numeric so that I can do calculations on those specific columns.

Comment: how about putting in a negative value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, no.  Data types need to be consistent since things like indexing and ordering is based on that fact.

I'd create a new *Exception* column with this information.  The numeric column would be `null`, and the `Exception` column would have a status such as `INJ`.

Another, albeit hacky, way would be to use certain *reserved* numbers as exceptions.  For example, `-1` could be `INJ` and `-2` could be something else.  These would have to be numbers that would never be valid in any other case.

Short of that, you'd have to make it a text column and do your own custom validation, which is *probably* going to break a lot of your code that assumes these values are numeric.